# pentaho dashboard drill down

Tags: drilldown, pentaho-cde

I'm working on pentaho dashboard drill down option passing parameter. While clicking on the first dashboard chart it's giving alert messages and also it's moving to dashboard. But in the second dashboard it's showing empty data. I don't know where I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer for my question.

We should use custom parameter in the second dashboard with the following java script code.

```
function x(){
//Dashboards.fireChange("statusname",Dashboards.getQueryParameter('param_order_status'));
return Utils.getQueryParameter('param_order_status');
//return 'Open';}
```

Hope this will be useful.